# Invalid first argument. It must be a callback function

Tags: selenium, jestjs

I am new to jest with selenium automation test. I am trying to add a beforeAll() and afterAll() functions to open and close the browsers once and run all the tests across multiple files, instead of calling it individually in all the files and opening multiple browsers and loading the website everytime.

Here is my test:
enter image description here

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJZQ.png)

[This is beforeAll() and afterAll() methods sitting in a separate file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYKoU.png)

[Actual Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZNnt.png)

Comment: This test works when adding beforeAll() and afterAll() in all individual files.

Comment: Re-edit your question. Don't paste screenshot of code. Highlight it with code markups.

Answer (score 1):

`beforeAll` is different from `it` or `describe`. The first argument can only be empty or with `done` if you using callback:

```js
// works
beforeEach((done) => {
 ...
 done()
});

// works
beforeEach(() => {
 return asyncSomething()
});

// Doesn't work. 
beforeEach(("Don't add string here") => {..});
```